# Laptop running at max speed when idling? But the fan works fine during gaming

Tags: laptop, fan

I have an Asus ROG laptop, I have this issue for a while now, thinking it was a problem windows update. But I did not create a restore point so I couldn't restore.

As the title has suggested, the fan runs at max speed when idling, but it works fine when I was playing game. So my solution for now is to play metal gear solid V for like 5 minutes then close it and the fan works normal for the whole day.

Is there any solution to this? It really seems like a software issues rather than a hardware issues. And how is this even possible?

Edit: 
[This is the screenshot when the fan is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK7u1.png)

Edit2:
[Task Manager Screenshot when fan is blowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZFkf.png)
[ROG gaming center when fan is blowing, I forgot to show the fan rpm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od6FJ.jpg)

Edit3:
[Fan speed blowing when not using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNlTt.png)
[CPUID screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUZFf.png)

Comment: Make sure you are using the Balanced Power Plan (not High Performance). Power Plans are in Control Panel, Power Options.

Comment: Have you opened Task Manager and view the operations? Could be anti-virus in the background or other(s) using alot of CPU processes.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of issue you'd have if Windows Update would do. Please post pictures using Task Manager or a software like HwMonitor.

Comment: @John Hi I have put the balanced power plan to balanced.

Comment: @vssher is not CPU fan running, is gpu fan running even when the usage is clearly 0%

Comment: @NatsuKage I'll get a screenshot when the fan is crazy again

Comment: Seeing a lot of posts on internet that say this CPU overheats. @Darkoftheknight  Install this app when it starts running the fans: https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html  And post a screenshot of it.

Comment: Hi I added the screenshot for you, any idea what might be the problem

Answer (score 1):

My laptop has been running fine for two days now. I'm not sure what I have done, I think is the maximum lifespan mode having problem with the fan. Asus has a maximum lifespan mode that will stop battery charging over a certain limit.

Close that program and everything works fine.